# Alias Function in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

I am trying to find dependencies in the variables of a Logistic Regression model I am building. I used the following call for the same:

```r
log_model <- glm(Target~.,data = base,family = "binomial")
al <- alias(log_model)
```

As an output I got three variables, so I removed two of them, and ran the same code again for rest of the variables. However, I am still getting the third variable as the output of the alias step. How is that possible, how can only one variable be dependent? I have also checked all the coefficients in the output, which has only one row, and all of which are zeros.

The Output:

|  | Intercept | A1 | A2 | A3 | ........ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ....... |

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but the `partial` argument of `alias` expects a *logical* value. You can’t pass a numeric value to it.

Comment: It gives the same result with `al <- alias(log_model)`.

Comment: Please show the output of `alias`, i.e. `al`. I'm not sure from your description what exactly the issue is. Does one variable perhaps only contain one unique value (and therefore has perfect correlation with the intercept)?

Comment: The issue is how come there's only one variable in the output, for the dependencies to exist there has to be at least two variables. The output is a data frame with one row, having the name of the variable, and all the entries of the row, for rest of the columns, including the intercept, are zeros.